# What methods can reduce JDBC thread pauses?

Tags: java, mysql, database, multithreading, jdbc

We are running a Java server application which needs to fetch information from a MySQL database in order to display data to the connected client. However, due to the many clients connected at a single time, it has to perform many queries in a short amount of time.

As a result of this, there is major lag/delay and threads will deadlock and pause until the query is complete...

**Are there any methods that we can use to prevent the thread from locking up whilst waiting for the database apart from making it async, because we need the data in sync?**

I've seen things such as connection pooling however we need a way to fetch data from the database in sync, without making the rest of the server application lag.

It should be when a user hits *x*, *y* will happen instead of user hits *x*, the program locks up and pauses for 2 seconds then *y* will happen once the query is complete.

Comment: Do you really have a single database connection for a *server* application?

Comment: We have priority connections, so the queries go to different connections depending on the priority of them. Also, this server is small, the database is huge though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection pooling is definitely the way to go.

If you are using a web application such as GlassFish, this can be carried out by creating a Connection Pool to a database (such as MySQL) and then use a JNDI naming service to access that Pool. This combination makes a much more efficient use of database access.

This [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html) is excellent for that.

Comment: I've just implemented BoneCP in to my server code and it is running even slower now... A single connection can do 100 iterations in 3000ms and a multi-threaded connection can do 100 iterations in 5600ms. Eeek! Have I done something wrong?

Comment: May I ask, what application server are you using as that can also have an impact on performance?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any other solution except by using (an optimized) connection pooling. You can lookup how you can optimize a connection pool by clicking [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/optimize.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Connection pooling will essentially open multiple connections and it'll use the first open connection so it can run more than one query at a time. Right?

Comment: Yes it opens multiple connections (cache of connections) that can be used by any requests. If a new request comes and there is no available connection, a new connection is created.

Answer (score 0):

Also, since your database is huge, verify that you have proper indexes for *all* your queries, that MySQL uses them and that writers have precedence over readers.